# Windows Timer Resolution vs Application Priority vs Processor scheduling

Tags: windows, performance, visual-c++, windows-services

Please, make it once more clear the technical difference between these three things around MS Windows systems. First is `Timer Resolution` you may set and get via ntdll.dll non-exported functions `NtSetTimerResolution` and `NtQueryTimerResolution` or use the Sysinternals' `clockres.exe` tool.

One of the scandalous trick used by the Chrome browser some time ago to perform better across the web. (They left high resolution trick for Flash plugin only at the moment). https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153139 
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/

In fact Visual Studio and SQL Server in some cases do the trick as well. I personally feel like it performs the whole system better and crisp, not slow down as many people warn out there.

What is the difference between the timer resolution and application I/O and memory priority (realtime/high/above normal/normal/low/background/etc.) you may set via Task Manager except the fact that the timer resolution sets up for the whole system, not a single application?

What is the difference between them and `Processor scheduling` option you can adjust from `CMD > SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe` -> Advanced tab. By default, the users' OS versions (like XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10) set the performance of programs, the servers' versions (2k3/2k8/2k12/2k16) do care of background services. How this option interacts with those two above?

Comment: `NtSetTimerResolution` and `NtQueryTimerResolution` is *exported* - so you easy call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timeBeginPeriod() is the documented api to do this.  It is documented to affect the accuracy for Sleep().  Dave Cutler probably did not enjoy implementing it, but allowing Win 3.1 code to port made it necessary.  The multi-media api back then was necessary to keep anemic hardware with small buffers going without stuttering.

Very crude, but there is no other good way to do it in the kernel.  The normal state for a processor core is to be stopped on a HLT instruction.  Consuming (almost) no power, the only way to revive it is with a hardware interrupt.  Which is what it does, it cranks up the clock interrupt rate.  Normally ticks 64 times per second, you can jack it up to 1000 with timeBeginPeriod, 2000 with the native api.

And yes, pretty bad for power consumption.  The clock interrupt handler also activates the thread scheduler, an fairly unsubtle chunk of code.  The reason why a Sleep() call can now wake up at (almost) the clock interrupt rate.  Tinkered with in Win8.1 btw, the only thing I noticed about the changes is that it is not quite as responsive anymore and a 1 msec rate can cause up to 2 msec delays.

Chrome is indeed notorious for ab/using the heck out of it.  I always assumed that it provided a competitive edge for a company that does big business in mobile operating systems and battery-powered devices.  The guy that started this web site [noticed something was wrong](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-does-windows-have-terrible-battery-life/).  The more responsible thing to do for a browser is to bump up the rate to 10 msec, necessary to get accurate GIF animation.  Multi-media playback does not need it anymore.

This otherwise has no effect at all on scheduling priorities.  One detail I did not check is if the thread quantum changes correspondingly (the number of ticks a thread may own a core before being evicted, 3 for a workstation).  I suspect it does.